# Any trick to use my 2008 iMac (mini-DVI) as a secondary monitor for my MacBook Pro?

Tags: imac, display

I have a 2008 iMac (with mini-DVI and NO Thunderbolt) and I want to use it as a secondary monitor for my MacBook Pro.

The [FAQ for Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204592) says that it's possible to do it with an 2009 or later iMac but not with the 2008 version I have.

Are there any tricks to do it by adding any kind of software, hardware, cables or adapters?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - add a Mini DisplayPort port to your iMac. Should only take an engineer and a machine shop to accomplish.

In all seriousness, the mini-DVI port on your iMac is an output-only port, whereas the Thunderbolt/Mini DisplayPort ports also accept input. No amount of software, cables or dongles will change that.